# Getting the value from a position in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a question about how to obtain the value of from a position in a multidimensional array.
What I figured would work would be taking the position and converting that into a string but that does not seem to work. What I want to do is compare the values in them to determine when certain values are the same. (I am making a tic tac toe game for class). Right now it is not working properly when I tested it it does not obtain the value from the position rather just says something along the lines of "function" instead of "o" or something.

Here is my code:

```
            var a1 = currentTTT[0][0].toString;
        var a2 = currentTTT[0][1].toString;
        var a3 = currentTTT[0][2].toString;
        var b1 = currentTTT[1][0].toString;
        var b2 = currentTTT[1][1].toString;
        var b3 = currentTTT[1][2].toString;
        var c1 = currentTTT[2][0].toString;
        var c2 = currentTTT[2][1].toString;
        var c3 = currentTTT[2][2].toString;


        if(a1 === a2 === a3){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a1 + "WINS!")
        }else if(b1 === b2 === b3){
            message.channel.sendMessage(b1 + "WINS!")
        }else if(c1 === c2 === c3){
            message.channel.sendMessage(c1 + "WINS!")
        }else if(a1 === b1 === c1){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a1 + "WINS!")
        }else if(a2 === b2 === c2){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a2 + "WINS!")
        }else if(a3 === b3 === b3){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a3 + "WINS!")
        }else if(a1 === b2 === c3){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a1 + "WINS!")
        }else if(a3 === b2 === c1){
            message.channel.sendMessage(a3 + "WINS!")
        }else{
            message.channel.sendMessage(a1)
        }
```

If anyone has ideas I would appreciate it.

Comment: It’s not clear why you need `toString`, but if you’re going to use it, it’s a function, you need to call it: `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `.toString()`  in the comments, you can't do this:

```
if(a1 === a2 === a3){
```

You should break it up

```
if(a1 === a2 && a1 === a3){
```